# Dividing coordinate into unit cube

Tags: java, coordinates, perlin-noise

I'm trying to write a Java class to generate Perlin Noise from a Cartesian coordinate. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://flafla2.github.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html) but I am struggling to understand the theory.

Specifically, how do you divide coordinates into a unit square or unit cube?

My original though was to a find which was higher the X or Y, then divide one by the other, So either X = 1, y < 1, or Y = 1, X < 1. But doing this doesn't really make sense as the point would always lie on one of the cube/square vertices.

Can someone explain the math to me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, we divide the x, y, and z coordinates into unit cubes. In other words, find `[x,y,z] % 1.0` to find the coordinate's location within the cube.

What that means is you perform the `value % 1.0` operation for each member of the `[x,y,z]` vector (*the position*):

`[x', y', z'] = [x % 1.0, y % 1.0, z % 1.0]`

`x'`, `y'`, and `z'` are the [remainders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) of dividing each **floating-point** coordinate by 1.0.

In other words, they are the amount you "chop off" of each coordinate when you round towards zero.

`[x', y', z']` represents the position inside a unit cube, from 0.0 to 1.0 on each axis.
But you can also imagine that unit cube is actually positioned in 3D space at the rounded (*towards zero*) coordinates of `[(int)x, (int)y, (int)z]`.

Another way to visualize what `[x', y', z']` means is to imagine a 1x1x1 grid superimposed over your game world. Each cell in the grid is a unit cube. If you have a point *anywhere* in that game world, it must be inside of of those cubes. `[x', y', z']` is telling you where the point is *inside* that cube.

The original position can be recovered by adding the position *of* the unit cube and the position *inside* the unit cube:
`[x, y, z] = [(int)x, (int)y, (int)z] + [x % 1.0, y % 1.0, z % 1.0]`

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I understand what it means now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually 3D Perlin noise would look a bit like this:

```
float PerlinNoise(Vector3 point) {

    Vector3Int root = new Vector3Int(
         FloorToInt(point.x),
         FloorToInt(point.y),
         FloorToInt(point.z));

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Vector3Int corner = root + cornerOffset[i];
        Vector3 gradient = GetPerlinGradient(corner);
        contribution[i] = Vector3.Dot(gradient, point - corner);
     }

     Vector3 pointInCell = point - root;

     return Interpolate(
         Interpolate(
              Interpolate(
                   contribution[0],
                   contribution[1],
                   pointInCell.x
              ),
              Interpolate(
                   contribution[4],
                   contribution[5],
                   pointInCell.x
              ),
              pointInCell.y
         ),
         Interpolate(
              Interpolate(
                   contribution[3],
                   contribution[2],
                   pointInCell.x
              ),
              Interpolate(
                   contribution[7],
                   contribution[6],
                   pointInCell.x
              ),
              pointInCell.y
         ),
         pointInCell.z
     );
}
```

So dividing space into repeated cubes is just a matter of rounding/flooring the coordinate. The position within this cell is just the fraction left over.

Comment: thanks for the code sample. I can use this later